# Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server. please

Tags: php

when I upload a file it won't redirect in my save_file.php. it keeps getting an error "Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server."

here is my code from my index.php:

```
 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="save_file.php">
                    <input type="file" name="file" size="4" style="background-color:#fff;" required="required" />
                    <br />
                    <input type="hidden" name="stud_no" value="<?php echo $fetch['stud_no']?>"/>
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="save"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add File</button>
                </form>
```

code from my save_file.php:

```
<?php
    
    require_once(realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]) .'\INOACPortal.com.ph\config.php');
    if(ISSET($_POST['save'])){
        $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
        $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
        $file_temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $location = "files/".$user_id."/".$file_name;
        $date = date("Y-m-d, h:i A");
        if(!file_exists("files/".$user_id)){
            mkdir("files/".$user_id);
        }
        
        if(move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $location)){
            mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `201_files` VALUES('', '$file_name', '$file_type', '$date', '$user_id')") or die(mysqli_error());
            header('location: 201files/index.php');
        }
    }
?>
```

my idea is when I click add file it will be redirected to save_file.php to process the insertion into the database.

Comment: what's the structure of your project folder. Does the html file and the save_file.php resides in the same path folder? Also, it's not clear if ``save_file.php`` is not found or ``...INOACPortal.com.ph\config.php`` ?